# label.visible = true not working on button click

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, sleep

On a button click, I am showing a label which displays the message "Please wait" and I am doing a Thread.sleep for 3 secs and then doing response.redirect to another page. the code is as follows:

```
        lblmsg.Visible = true;

        Thread.Sleep(3000);

        Response.Redirect("demo2.aspx");
```

My understanding is that, the label has to show and then process waits for 3 secs and then redirects?? Let me know why this doesnt work, and what is the workaround.

Comment: I believe that you try to do "a trick" that must be done on client side, with javascript. With or with out the sleep, with the redirect you make, the page will not be rendered again with the msg to be hide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is server side code so `lblmsg.Visible = true;` sets the label to be visible but that label has not yet been sent to the browser at this point so it won't be visible to the end user.

Here's what happens:

- User hits page in browser
- Asp receives the request and starts running the page code
- The server label has it's visible property set to true
- The server waits
- The server sends a redirect message back to the browser
- The browser receives the redirect

You might consider hiding and showing a message on the browser side using jQuery before you send your request to the server - something like this (or perhaps replace the link with a button):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready() {
        $("#someLink").click(function() {
            $("#waitMessage").show();
        });
    });
<script>

<p id="waitMessage" style="display:none;">Please wait</p>

<a id="someLink" href="pagewithwait">Do stuff</a>
```

Comment: How other way can i achieve the functionality that I want...when user clicks a button I need to show a message like ' processing please wait' and then in a few secs redirect to another page..any ideas wud b appreciated.

Comment: @Phani you need to use javascript to do this.